# Automatically Send File from Flex over http

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, file, transfer

I have a database file I need to send to a PHP controller for synchronization. I can access the standard file upload methods in AS3 but they all require user interaction. I need this take place behind the scenes. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link suggested by cbroughton works with AIR application. Only file you are able to read via html page ..from clients computer.. without requiring user interaction.. is SharedObject (like a cookie).

Comment: Thanks, this is where I keep coming back to. I will have to resort to timestamp quires on both databases to transfer all of the information.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am sure there is a way for the user to give you a permanent grant on a file within the flash objects directory; but anywhere else on the file-system would worry me if this behavior existed.

See: [This link](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=179535) for a possible sub-solution.